# is there a way to have parameters be executed in random order in python cli?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, command-line-interface

i have a program that takes 3 parameters: volume, weight, and model_path. Currently, i have:

```
 volume = int(args[0])
 weight = int(args[1])
 model_path = args[2]
```

so i have to execute it like this: `python3 example.py 713 382 model.pkl`. I want to be able to do it like this: `python3 example.py --weight=500 --volume=437 --model=model.pkl`, but in any order (so `python3 example.py --volume=3100 --model=model.pkl --weight=472`).

I tried

```
volume = int(args["--volume"])
weight = int(args["--weight"])
model_path = args["--model"]
```

and it said args could only be type slice or int, not string.

Comment: Use the `argparse` module. I don't know what `args` is; did you mean `sys.argv`?

Comment: yes, sorry. Is there a way to do this in native python?

Comment: `argparse` *is* native Python; it's part of the standard library. If you are asking how to reimplement `argparse` from scratch, recognize that `args[0] == '--weight=500'`; it's up to you to figure out what to *do* with that value. Separate the string into `weight` and `500`, then update a `dict`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the idea of reimplementing the `argparse` module, just *use* that module. For example,

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--volume', type=int)
p.add_argument('--weight', type=int)
p.add_argument('--model')

args = p.parse_args()
```

The result will be an instance of `argparse.Namespace`, which is just a very simple object with attributes associated with each argument you defined. For example, if you specify `--weight=500` or `--weight 500`, then `args.weight == 500`.